# How to parse each HCL dictionary item by golang?

Tags: go, hcl

I have tried to parse HCL config using `golang`, but it's not working.

```
type cfg_dict struct {
      name     string       `hcl:",key"`
      type     string       `hcl:"type"`
}

type hcl_config struct {
      config_items    cfg_dict      `hcl:"config"`
}

func main() {
    hcl_example = `config "cfg1" {
           type = "string"
    }`

    hcl_opts := &hcl_config{}

    hcl_tree, err := hcl.Parse(hcl_example)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if err := hcl.DecodeObject(&hcl_opts, hcl_tree); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(hcl_opts)
}
```

When I tried to run this test code after built, it shows empty value.

```
&{[]}
```

Is there any problem what I have to fix?

Comment: Export your struct fields; change the first letters of the field names to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Fields on the struct you are attempting to unmarshal from HCL need to be exported. To export the fields make the first character in the field name upper case.

```
type cfg_dict struct {
  Name     string       `hcl:",key"`
  Type     string       `hcl:"type"`
}

type hcl_config struct {
  Config_items    cfg_dict      `hcl:"config"`
}
```